# Match a value in the column and return another column in pandas | python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have an `input file1` of two columns(tab-separted):

```
c1\tc2
aaa\t232 65 19 32
bbew\t32 22 20
jhsi\t986 1 32 463 221
```

And `input file2` which have one column:

```
c1
19
1
32
277
```

what I want is to search an element from `file2` in `file1`, and return the corresponding value in `c1`. If there is more than one matched value, then return all together in one column.

Here is what should the output file be like:

```
19       aaa
1        jhsi
32       aaa bbew jhsi
277
```

`277` would be left empty because it does not exist.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't easily vectorisable. For performance, I suggest you perform your transformation before you put data in a Pandas dataframe. Here is a solution using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
# use set for O(1) lookup
scope_set = set(df2['c1'])

# initialise defualtdict of lists
dd = defaultdict(list)

# iterate and create dictionary mapping numbers to keys
for row in df1.itertuples(index=False):
    for num in map(int, row.c2.split()):
        if num in scope_set:
            dd[num].append(row.c1)

# construct dataframe from defaultdict
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': list(dd), 'keys': list(map(' '.join, dd.values()))})

# reindex to include blanks
df = df.set_index('num').reindex(sorted(scope_set)).reset_index()
```

**Result**

```
print(df)

   num           keys
0    1           jhsi
1   19            aaa
2   32  aaa bbew jhsi
3  277            NaN
```

**Setup**

```
from io import StringIO
from collections import defaultdict

file1 = StringIO("""c1\tc2
aaa\t232 65 19 32
bbew\t32 22 20
jhsi\t986 1 32 463 221""")

file2 = StringIO("""c1
19
1
32
277""")

df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, sep='\t')
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
```